# Default Windows Dialog Browsing does not show "My Computer" nor "Drives"

Tags: eclipse

Don't know if it's related to Eclipse, but it happened in Eclipse, so my first assunption will be, that it's something that has to do with Eclipse.

The problem is, for some strange reason, all of a sudden, whenever I can "browse" within Eclipse for a file/project, or whatever it is, the default window that is being shown does not contain any drives on my computer, and only a Desktop plus my user's windows folder. It is shown below:

[image]

As you clearly see, there is no way to go to the "My Computer" or any drive. I have a workaround (for now), but it will become pretty irritating fast, so I'm looking for a solution that caused all this. The workaround anyway, is typing the "C:\" or any drive letter, and hitting Browse button afterwards. If I do this, all is back to normal:

[image]

Anybody can help out a fellow programmer, who had the same weird case?

Comment: That looks like an Eclipse bug and therefore doesn't belong here. I suggest you open a bug report in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank God, the internet. After searching for almost 2 hours for this, I got lucky and found this thread:

http://forums.cnet.com/7723-19411_102-412058/browse-for-folder-missing-computer-and-libraries/

Well, when you have 16GB of RAM, 2 monitors, and 2 SSD drives (for some of you it might not be much, but for me it is), you kinda tend to loose yourself into thinking how "powerful" your machine is ;).

The answer was just like for the user in the above thread. I did have a lot of items on my desktop, that increased today. Seems at one point today I "crossed" the magical line, which broke the "Browse Dialog".

In anyway, posting here, if someone else will run into this issue in the future. I hope it will be helpful to someone.